# Fail2ban won't start via /etc/init.d/fail2ban but will via /usr/bin/fail2ban-client

Tags: linux, redhat, fail2ban

I've been running fail2ban successfully for a long time on RHEL.

Now all of a sudden starting, stopping and restarting via /etc/init.d/fail2ban no longer works:

```
# /etc/init.d/fail2ban start
Starting fail2ban: [  OK  ]

# service fail2ban status
Fail2ban (pid 31808) is running...
ERROR  Unable to contact server. Is it running?

# /etc/init.d/fail2ban stop
Stopping fail2ban: [FAILED]
```

However if I do it this way it works:

```
# /usr/bin/fail2ban-client start
2014-02-11 15:46:13,863 fail2ban.server : INFO   Starting Fail2ban v0.8.4
2014-02-11 15:46:13,863 fail2ban.server : INFO   Starting in daemon mode

# /usr/bin/fail2ban-client status
Status
|- Number of jail:      10
`- Jail list: ...

#/usr/bin/fail2ban-client stop
Shutdown successful
```

The file /etc/init.d/fail2ban hasn't changed and I can't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

There was a rogue fail2ban process running. After I killed it, fail2ban now restarts in the usual manner.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue too! Could you please tell me how you did this. Thanks!

Comment: It was a while ago so I don't recall. I'm guessing I did `top` found the process in question and did `kill pid` but that's assuming you have a rogue process running like I did

Answer (score 0):

edited: commands mentioned is now the standardized "systemctl" instead of the old deprecated "service" as per @Michael Hampton currect suggestion :)

To kill any old processes of fail2ban you have a clean way and a dirty way as explained below.

**Clean:** this will also make sure no old rules/bans are left in the firewall

```
sudo systemctl stop fail2ban.service 
sudo systemctl restart fail2ban.service
```

**Dirty (1):** Some rules might not be removed correctly

```
# ps -au |grep fail2ban
# killall <pid>
# systemctl restart fail2ban.service
```

**Dirty (2):** Some rules might not be removed correctly

```
# killall fail2ban
# systemctl restart fail2ban.service
```

Comment: Remember that `service` is deprecated and you should be using `systemctl` now.

Comment: Thank you Michael for the suggestion, I edited the code to respect the new standards